# Excel: Freezing simultaneously a column and a row

Tags: excel

In Excel 2016 I know how to freeze the first column or the first row through the menu View -> Freeze Panes.

But how can I simultaneously freeze both the first column and the first row?

When I apply one of them it removes the other one.

How can I freeze any column or row not the first ones?

@gravity, this is your suggestion:
[image]

I don't have that option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you select cell B2, and under "View," choose "Freeze Panes," the first column AND row will be frozen simultaneously.

Expanding upon this, if you choose the upper-left most, singular cell, that you do not want to be frozen, and choose freeze panes, all panes above and to the left of that single cell are frozen.

Comment: I've pasted a screenshot in the main question.  I don't have that option, only unfreeze panes, freeze top row and freeze first column.

Comment: Unfreeze your panes first (since you've already incorrectly frozen a row or column by itself), *make sure you have the top-most left-most CELL (not row or column) you DON'T want frozen selected (probably B2)*, then simply choose "Freeze Panes" again.  You need to simply start over.

Comment: I'm sorry I was trying. By selecting A1 I got to freeze columns and rows, but not the first column and first row. Strangely it freezes rows 1 to 19, and columns A to G

Comment: You should not be selecting A1 at all.  Click 'Unfreeze Panes,' first.  Then, click **only in cell B2**.  Then, click 'Freeze Panes' again, and both Column A, and Row 1 will automatically be frozen.

Comment: OK, I don't know what I was doing wrong. Now it works, thanks.